# Multiple response assertions and Xpath assertions not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Multiple response assertions and Xpath assertions not working see below.could you please explain it with example?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be a lot easier to use 4 separate assertions like:

[image: JMeter several separate assertions.]

Combining several clauses into single assertion is also possible, for example:

- there are `|` and `and` [XPath operators](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp)
- there is `|` [regex meta character](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) to learn more about using assertions in JMeter tests.

Comment: When combining several clauses into single Response assertion->pattern to test for example:
http:abc1.com.html|http:abc1.com.html|  Do you think this is working becoause it was not working for me?

Comment: Given you choose `Contains` pattern matching rule it should work. Also the last `|` is not required

Comment: http:abc1.com.html|http:abc1.com.html  --> Response Assertion failure message: TransformerException: Unknown error in XPath. Xpath assertion looks like //product/url = 'http:abc1.com.html' l //product/image 'http:abc2.com.html'

Comment: I was talking about response assertion, not the xpath assertion

Comment: Yes in response assertion 'Contains' pattern matching rule is used. isn't possible to combining several Xpath assertions?

Comment: It **is possible**, but you need to either learn some [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). I am not telepathic enough to suggest anything without seeing your response data and knowing what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58241/discussion-between-lak-and-dmitri-t).